# Search is not displaying any records in yii framework

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have this search form:

```
 <form method="GET" action="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;?>/telephone/search/">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name or Telephone no." required>
    <input type="submit" class="btn-btn-default" value="search"></form>
```

And this controller action:

```
public function actionSearch()
    {
            $request = Yii::$app->request;
            $name=$request->get('name');    
            $search=Telephone::find()->where('Name LIKE :substr', array(':substr' => '%$name%'))->all(); 
            return $this->render('search',['search'=>$search]);

    }
```

and this view:

```
<table border='1' class='table table-hover table-striped'>
<thead style='background-color:silver'><tr><td>S.N.</td><td>Name</td><td>Telephone No.</td><td>Mobile No.</td><td width="24%">Options</td></tr></thead>
<?php $i=0;?>
<?php foreach ($search as $sear): ?>
<tr><td><?php $i++; echo $i ;?></td><td><?=$sear->Name?></td><td><?=$sear->Telephone?></td><td><?=$sear->Mobile?></td>
<td><a href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;?>/telephone/view/<?php echo $sear->id;?>" data-id=""><button>View details</button></a>
<a href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;?>/telephone/edit/<?php echo $sear->id;?>" data-id=""><button>Edit</button></a>
<a href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;?>/telephone/delete/<?php echo $sear->id;?>" data-id=""><button>Delete</button></a></td></tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

but the search records are not displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have single quotes when defining :substr $name
please change that to `"%$name%"`

Also read this
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php